# How does 'bash' or 'gnome-terminal' print user and path information?

Tags: bash, terminal, pipe

I am wondering if there is a different mechanism between printing user and path information(e.g. "guest:~/home/guest$") and command outputs.

When I try to PIPE stdin and stdout of "bash", I can only get command outputs but not user and path information.

```
self.p = Popen(["bash", "-i"], bufsize=1, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
self.p.stderr = self.p.stdout

self.t = Thread(target=self.listen_stdout)
self.t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
self.t.start()

def listen_stdout(self):
    while True:
        c = self.p.stdout.read(1)
        print c,
```

When I run the above code and write `ls` to `self.p.stdin`, it does only print content of the folder but not `guest:~/home/guest$`.

It goes same with password prompt of `ssh` and `sudo`.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: @michas Trying to use bash commands on web page. Sending input to server and getting output from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` has both an interactive mode and a batch mode. It enters the corresponding mode depending if stdin is a terminal or not.

```
bash        # interactive
cat|bash    # non-interactive: stdin is a pipe not a terminal
cat|bash -i # explicitly request interactive mode
```

In interactive mode `bash` will print a prompt (configurable by the PS1 variable) and also set up other things for a more user friendly environment.

Please read `man bash` and look for "interactive" for all the differences of those modes.

Comment: I don't get it. Even if I run as `bash -i`, `ssh` and `sudo` outputs to python script's terminal, not to piped stream. Somehow I could not read these from `self.p.stdout`. Even `bash` itself outputs some warning and error messages to terminal screen.